# Converting image-file into base64 in express nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, binary

I am trying to convert an image file into base64, so I can store in base64 string form in mongoDB.

This is how I am trying to do that:

```
router.post('/file_upload',function(req,res){

  function base64_encode(file) {
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}

  var ImageFileToSave =  base64_encode(req.body.file);

  console.log(ImageFileToSave);


})
```

**On Client side:**

```
<form action="/file_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-
 data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

This is the error that I am getting

> TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer

how can I convert that image file(eg:image.jpg) into base64?

Comment: What is the data type of req.body.file?

Comment: it is buffer i think

Comment: Btw, where do you get this error? client or server?

Comment: on server side.

Comment: Ok. Kindly check the value of req.body.file and its data type. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you have to use a body parser or for example multer? https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Have you implement this or not ? Actually I am getting confused when convert base64 to file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will need to use [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) middleware to handle `multipart/form-data`.

```
const express = require('express')
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

const app = express()

app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('example'), (req, res, next) => {
  // req.file is the `example` file or whatever you have on the `name` attribute: <input type="file" name="example" />
  // I believe it is a `Buffer` object.
  const encoded = req.file.buffer.toString('base64')
  console.log(encoded)
})
```

---

2018-10-24: See David's comment below.

2019-06-11: Fixed example based on comments. It is indeed `req.file.buffer`: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/storage/memory.js#L8

Comment: It didn't work to me, but with a little change it worked


const encoded = req.file.buffer.toString('base64');

Comment: Not sure if it was like this in older versions of Multer, but for me it worked with req.file.buffer.toString('base64') too. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 6):

As the previous answer wasn't working for me, I'm sharing this other one that worked.
I made with the multer library getting the file and then transforming it to base64

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({});

router.post('/uploadlogo', upload.single('logo'), (req, res, next) => {
    // encoded has the base64 of your file
    const encoded = req.file.buffer.toString('base64');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it manually in a way if you want more control. here is an example but you can implement it in any way you want, as middleware or as a function to call alone.

this is assuming your image is base64 which would be "req.body.image".

```js
var ImageMiddleware =  (req, res, next)=> {
  if (req.body.image && req.body.foldername && req.body.filename){
    const imagepath = req.body.foldername + "/" + uuidv4() + "_" + req.body.filename;

      function buff(data) {
        const base64 = data.split(',')[1];
        let buff = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64');
        return buff
      }

      fs.writeFileSync(imagepath, buff(req.body.image))

  }
}
```