# How to get the path of the file I selected in a form of input file so I can upload with cloudinary the server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forms, cloudinary

I am able to get the filename of a file under the picture object as seen in the image below [image: object]

and I make a request to cloudinary with the following, but it says the image path is not correct, which makes sense, but the object I have for the chosen picture does not show the image path.

So how do I get the correct path for cloudinary.

```
var cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

export default async function signup(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  const body = req.body;

  cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    `${body}`,
    function (error, result) {
      console.log(result, error);
    }
  );

  try {
    const result = req.body;
    res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(error.requestResult.statusCode).send(error.message);
  }
}
```

Here is what I am sending to the api

```
 const res = await fetch("../api/image", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data.picture[0].name),
    });

    console.log(res);
```

I am using react hook forms, and here is the whole code for context

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import ReactDatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { gql, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const CREATE_DECOR_ENTRY = gql`
  mutation CreateDecorEntry(
    $ownerID: ID!
    $description: String!
    $pieces: Int!
    $purchaser: String!
    $alterations: Boolean!
    $cost: Int!
    $purchaseDate: Date!
    $category: String!
  ) {
    createDecor(
      data: {
        description: $description
        pieces: $pieces
        purchaser: $purchaser
        alterations: $alterations
        cost: $cost
        purchaseDate: $purchaseDate
        category: $category
        owner: { connect: $ownerID }
      }
    ) {
      description
    }
  }
`;

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());
const fetchWithImage = (url, image) =>
  fetch(`${url}?image=${image}`).then((r) => r.json());

export default function Decor() {
  const { data: user, error: userError } = useSWR("/api/user", fetcher);

  const { data: cookieData, error: cookieError } = useSWR(
    "/api/cookie",
    fetcher
  );

  var cookieBearer = `Bearer ${cookieData}`;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Enter your Decor Data</h1>

      {user && cookieBearer && <Form user={user} cookieBearer={cookieBearer} />}
    </Layout>
  );
}

const Form = ({ cookieBearer, user }) => {
  const Router = useRouter();

  const [
    createDecorEntry,
    { data: createDecorEntryData, loading: saving },
  ] = useMutation(CREATE_DECOR_ENTRY, {
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: cookieBearer,
      },
    },
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);

    let yourDate = data.purchaseDate;

    const offset = yourDate.getTimezoneOffset();
    yourDate = new Date(yourDate.getTime() - offset * 60 * 1000);
    const date = yourDate.toISOString().split("T")[0];

    console.log(date);

    const dataMassage = {
      ...data,
      pieces: parseInt(data.pieces),
      cost: parseInt(data.cost),
      purchaseDate: date,
    };

    console.log(dataMassage);

    const res = await fetch("../api/image", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data.picture[0].name),
    });

    console.log(res);

    // const res = await createDecorEntry({
    //   variables: {
    //     ownerID: user.id,
    //     ...dataMassage,
    //   },
    // }).catch(console.error);

    // Router.push(`/decor/data`);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div>
        <h2>Image</h2>
        <input ref={register} type="file" name="picture" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Description"
          name="description"
          ref={register({ required: true })}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Number of Pieces</h2>
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Number of Pieces"
          name="pieces"
          ref={register({ required: true })}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Purchaser</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Purchaser"
          name="purchaser"
          ref={register({ required: true })}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Alternations Needed</h2>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          placeholder="Alternations Needed"
          name="alterations"
          ref={register({ required: true })}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Cost</h2>
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Cost"
          name="cost"
          ref={register({ required: true })}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Purchase Date</h2>
        <Controller
          name="purchaseDate"
          control={control}
          render={({ onChange, value }) => (
            <ReactDatePicker selected={value} onChange={onChange} />
          )}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Category</h2>
        <select name="category" ref={register}>
          <option value="Curation">Curation</option>
          <option value=" Good"> Good</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_and_video_upload#node_js_image_upload), you can't just upload file. You will have to either save it somewhere first (for example locally on disk), or [convert it into base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762165/converting-image-file-into-base64-in-express-nodejs).

Interestingly enough, other part of documentation suggests that you an send an [array buffer](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method), but I'm not sure if it is available in Node

Comment: Oh so I save it on the disk and use that path, or if I have the base64 what do I pass to cloudinary a long string instead of the file path

Comment: So on the action of hitting browse and after selecting it it needs to be converted to a baseString, and I need to run a server side function at that point to do so. When that's returned with the baseSring does react hook forms pick that up or something. Since it's registered to that input

Comment: You will have to convert base64 to data-uri first, but yes - you either pass local file path, or base64 data-uri. I'd go with local path - save temporary file, upload to cloudinary, delete temporary file.

Comment: ok, I'm doing some googling here, but where would I start to even save the temporary file, would I first being listening for a onChange event from the file input, but then not sure. Ill keep looking but if you know the direction that would help alot

Comment: So, you get your file in nodejs, right? You write this file to disk, using [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options). After your file saved on disk, pass it's path to cloundinary uploader. When upload complete - [delete](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlinksync_path) file from disk.

Comment: ok but once it hit's the node side I only have access to the filename how does fs know where to find it to save it.

Comment: I'm missing something fundamental in my thinking here

Comment: Oh. I see. You have to send whole file to node side. Not only name.

Comment: Oh the whole file object ok. I will try this now thanks

Comment: oh wait the event from a file input I am sending is what you are saying, not the picture object from the file after its selected

Comment: when you say send whole file to node side, what are you referring to. I can send the picture object, but I dont see how that helps,and then there is a event from the file onChange but I dont see how that could help either

Comment: or are you talking about picture[0] send that

Comment: I have been trying this for next js which I am using but still not sure what to pass it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60465564/create-upload-files-api-in-next-js

Comment: Got the buffer and sent that with streamifier. You can see in the code below. Thanks for thelp, and I chose your answer becasue it lead me to the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am only posting this answer so others can benefit, I ended up going the array buffer route.

```
import formidable from "formidable";
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
let streamifier = require('streamifier');

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

// first we need to disable the default body parser
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function image(req, res) {
  

  try {

    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = "./";
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(files));

    console.log(files.image.path);

    var oldPath = files.image.path;
    var rawData = fs.readFileSync(oldPath);

    console.log(rawData);

    let cld_upload_stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
      {
        folder: "sick-fits"
      },
      function(error, result) {
          console.log(error, result);
          res.status(200).send({ result });
      }
  );

  streamifier.createReadStream(rawData).pipe(cld_upload_stream);

  });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(error.requestResult.statusCode).send(error.message);
  }
}
```